# FirestorePagingOptions does not load any data from firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, firebaseui

**I want to paginate to load data from firestore. So that I use FirestorePagingOptions. But it does not load any data.**
When I load data by `.addSnapshotListener` it work fine.

I share my code below:

**Query:**

```
Query query = db.collection("YouTubeActivity").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

**PagedList Config:**

```
PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPageSize(3)
                .build();
```

**FirestorePagingOptions:**

```
FirestorePagingOptions<ActivityModel> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<ActivityModel>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(query,config,new SnapshotParser<ActivityModel>(){
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ActivityModel parseSnapshot(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "parseSnapshot: ");
                        ActivityModel activityModel = snapshot.toObject(ActivityModel.class);
                        return activityModel;
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

**Adapter:**

```
new FirestorePagingAdapter<ActivityModel,ActivityViewHolder>(options){

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ActivityViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_list_itme_layout,parent,false);

                return new ActivityViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ActivityViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final ActivityModel model) {
                holder.txt_title.setText(model.getTitle());

            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
                super.onError(e);
                Log.d(TAG, "onError: "+e.getMessage());
            }


            @Override
            protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
                super.onLoadingStateChanged(state);

                switch (state){
                    case ERROR:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onLoadingStateChanged: Error Loading");
                }
            }
        };
```

**setAdapter:**

```
activityRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
activityRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
activityRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Structure of my firestore YouTubeActivity collection:**

[image]

**I can not figure out what is the problem. Please help me how to solve this issue.**

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I updated my question please relook. @AlexMamo

Comment: If you try to log the value of `model.getTitle()` in onBindViewHolder(), is it something printed out in the logcat? Besides that, if you remove this line `activityRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` is something displayed in the RecyclerView?

Comment: I try both ways but it does show anything in logcat. @AlexMamo

Comment: From this line: `new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<ActivityModel>().setLifecycleOwner(this)`, I understand that you are trying to pass a `Lifecycler`, in order to listen automatically for data. Did you try to start and stop listening for data manually? If not, could you try this and report back the result?